# NextJS how build pages structure for dynamic path

Tags: next.js

I develop app, where pages routing configures by cms,
as exam. site.com/products/..., site.com/search etc.

This is multi country app and I need internationalise routing in the next way:
France -  site.com/produits/... , site.com/rechercher .

Also I want leave ability choosing Server rendering for some pages and Static for other.

`rewrites`  - https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/rewrites is wrong way because new pages can be added at run time

can you recommend me `pages` dir structure or architecture for this needs?